# How can I prevent selecting text in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript

Doesn't oEvent.preventDefault(); work in GC? I need to prevent selecting text when the onmove event is triggered.

**EDIT:** It turns out to be very easy...

```
function disableSelection() {
   document.onselectstart = function() {return false;} // ie
   document.onmousedown = function() {return false;} // others
}
function enableSelection() {
   document.onselectstart = null; // ie
   document.onmousedown = null; // others
}
```

After that, there's no text selection triggered on the move event (ie. on the select event -- ie - indeed ie!)

Comment: In my opinion it is better to do it via this method (or `event.preventDefault()` which is equivalent but a bit more modern) than to try to suppress the selection through CSS attributes which differ between browser and aren't that predictable.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`-webkit-user-select: none` CSS style controls whether the user is allowed to select the
text of the element.

For completeness sake, this covers all supporting browsers (IE is not considered a web browser):

```
.no-select
{
   user-select: none;
   -o-user-select:none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

To do it through Javascript, just create a class and add the node's attributes.

Comment: IE is not considered a web browser? How's that?

Comment: Search in stackoverflow's question database, see how many 'Works on firefox, doesn't work on IE' questions you can find :)

Comment: You could add -o-user-select:none to the list for Opera support

Comment: what browsers does `user-select: none;` work for, since it doesn't work on Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: +1 for the answer, +1 for the IE bashing. Bah, we can only give a single +1 :) Bashing IE is always `Time.now` as long as it's available.

Comment: For those who work in places that do need IE, IE10 added support for this using `-ms-user-select`

Comment: I love how easy it is to find these in Stackoverflow. Then it's the just the matter of hitting Ctrl-Shift-I to bring Chrome developer tools, search and delete the pointless attributes above in the page and tada: text selection is back.

Comment: @MarkH Well yes, but I don't think anyone's trying to claim that it's a foolproof way to stop a user getting the content if they want to. There are other use cases, many of which are aesthetic.

Answer (score 19):

To do it using JavaScript:

```
var el = document.getElementById("myElement"), s = el.style;
s.userSelect = "none";
s.webkitUserSelect = "none";
s.MozUserSelect = "none";
el.setAttribute("unselectable", "on"); // For IE and Opera
```

Note that for IE and Opera, the `unselectable` attribute isn't inherited by an element's children, so any child elements of `el` will also need `unselectable` to be set to `"on"`.