# Prevent text selection when dragging from outside target in IE7/8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

It has been discussed how to disable text from being selected:
[How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

However, I have yet to find a solution that blocks the user from selecting text when dragging from outside the intended target.  I'm looking for a solution that works in IE 7/8.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making things unselectable in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448671/making-things-unselectable-in-ie)

Answer (score 1):

The IE8- [onselectstart event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212542/how-can-i-prevent-selecting-text-in-google-chrome) and [unselectable attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448671/making-things-unselectable-in-ie) solutions have already been discussed.

The [CSS solution](http://arguments.callee.info/2010/07/04/unselectable-text-using-css-and-javascript/) has been published as well. Here is the gist:

```
<!-- save this file as unselectable.htc and remember where you put it -->
<public:component lightweight="true">
    <public:attach event="ondocumentready" onevent="unselectable()" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function unselectable(){
            element.onselectstart = function(){ return false; };
            element.setAttribute('unselectable', 'on', 0);
        }
    </script>
</public:component>

/* add this rule to the existing CSS file */
.unselectable {
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    behavior: url(unselectable.htc); /* change this path as needed */
}
```