# Disable Text Selection in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, textselection

I am trying to disable text selection, and it works fine in all browsers but IE. I have added a bit of code to the css as well as to the index. It still is not disabling.

I have added this to the index:

```
$('#poet').disableSelection(); // deprecated in jQuery UI 1.9

$(el).attr('unselectable','on')
.css({'-moz-user-select':'-moz-none',
       '-moz-user-select':'none',
       '-o-user-select':'none',
       '-khtml-user-select':'none', /* you could also put this in a class */
       '-webkit-user-select':'none',/* and add the CSS class here instead */
       '-ms-user-select':'none',
       'user-select':'none'
 }).bind('selectstart', function(){ return false; });

 $("#123").bind( "selectstart", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

 $("#123").bind("selectstart", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

And this to the .css file:

```
* {
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none; 
-ms-user-select:none;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add both of these to your existing CSS class

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
user-select: none;
```

Additionally, you can check this link for more details.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj152140(v=vs.85).aspx

---

[Prevent text selection when dragging from outside target in IE7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692036/prevent-text-selection-when-dragging-from-outside-target-in-ie7-8)

---

Given that this post specifies "jquery" :

```
$("#inputID").focus(function() {
    $(this).blur();
}):
```

Comment: How would a new `-webkit` be helpful in making it work with `IE` ?

Comment: @Cristy By looking at his code sample it's apparent that he's trying to disable selection for all browsers (including IE). These were the only two missing from his class to complete that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @adam, but for some reason it is still not working. My code now contains:

    /**STOP_HIGHLIGHTING**/
    * {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    }

Comment: and the javascript contains:
    $(el).attr('unselectable','on')
     .css({'-moz-user-select':'-moz-none',
           '-moz-user-select':'none',
           '-o-user-select':'none',
           '-khtml-user-select':'none', 
           '-webkit-user-select':'none',
           '-ms-user-select':'none',
           'user-select':'none'
     }).bind('selectstart', function(){ return false; });



     $("#123").bind("selectstart", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#inputID").focus(function() {
    $(this).blur();
    }):

Comment: @adam I am much more skilled with HTML and CSS, as for jQuery goes, I just copy and paste code I find, and have done a few lessons in code academy. Could you explain what jQuery blur means? I do have this at the end:

    $("#inputID").focus(function() {
    $(this).blur();
    }):

Comment: @adam going against conventions, I even tried adding !important to each item to no avail.

Comment: If you're not familiar with using jQuery and ready to try a jQuery solution, you may want to think about not tagging the post with 'jQuery' =P

Comment: @adam I have tried one by one unlinking all linked files to see if one of them was causing a conflict. Nothing. I am running IE 8, does that help?

Comment: @adam Haha I am sorry, after the CSS solution did not work I saw a jQuery solution online and thought I'd give it a shot.

Comment: Check this link out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692036/prevent-text-selection-when-dragging-from-outside-target-in-ie7-8

Comment: @MichaelCarafa Glad you eventually got something that will work.  Will you please update your OP with the working solution.